# Serialize custom external class that is not serializable

Tags: c#, serialization

I wonder if there is any possibility of serializing a class described in a topic.

Suppose we have someone's library that is shared as binary `DLL` file. Additionally a creator of this lib created a class that is not `Serializable`. How to serialize such a class? I know I can create a twin-class that contains all the poperties etc. that can be serialized. But is there any other, easier solution to do this? How do you serialize classes that are "not yours" and are stored as binary only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd party class is an implementation detail; frankly, it is a very bad idea to involve this in your serialization, as you are then completely fenced into a corner, and can never change implementation. You would also face significant risk of versioning issues - something that `BinaryFormatter` simply doesn't handle well.

It might not be what you **want** to hear, but I offer two recommendations:

1. do not serialize implementation details; serialize the *data* (only); this may indeed require you to write a DTO that mirrors the implementation, but this is usually a trivial job
2. make sure you understand the implications of `BinaryFormatter`; frankly, I never recommend it - it has... glitches.

As for workarounds: you *can* investigate serialization surrogates, but that isn't a trivial thing to do inside `BinaryFormatter`, and is basically just a re-statement of the first bullet.

If it was me (although I am hugely biased), I would change serializer; protobuf-net (disclosure: I'm the author) works as a binary serializer, and has easy-to-implement support for surrogates if the third-party model is already coupled to your model.

Comment: I think I used to touch `protobuf-net` one day in the past:D Glad to meet the Author!!! Good job mate!